# Clear mail spool after every email sent through Cron tab PHP

Tags: php, yii2, cron, sendmail, swiftmailer

I am trying hard to find solution to stop my crontab sending emails twice after every call. It keeps sending emails twice to any user randomly on each call and specially when I am using BCC or CC or trying to send multiple emails. I am using Yii2 PHP for the same. My cron is running every 5 minutes and taking all the logged emails from my DB, send it to users and set the "email_sent" flag to 1. I doubt setting the flag can be the issue for this duplicates or not? Please help me if anyone know the code to clear or refresh spool mqueues from server through PHP. I am using Amazon SES SMTP for sending emails. I can not post the full code but the sendmail function I use is as below:

```
$config = [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => $host,
                'username' => $mail_from,
                'password' => $mail_pass,
                'port' => $port,
                'encryption' => $encryption,
            ],
        ];
        $yiiemail = Yii::createObject($config);
        $sendmail = $yiiemail->compose($text_body_style, ['content' => 
                    $body, 'theme' => $theme]);
        $sendmail->setFrom([EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS =>EMAIL_FROM_NAME]);
        $sendmail->setTo($email);
        $sendmail->setSubject($subject);
        if(!empty($bcc)){ 
            $sendmail->setBcc($bcc);
        }
        return $sendmail->send();
```

This code is running everytime the cron runs for each email. Please help me on how shall I resolve this.

Comment: Could it be possible that the function sending the mails is being called before all mails from the previous call are set to `email_sent = 1`? 

Also, have you checked the mail.log to see if there are any bounces?

Comment: I checked everything. I am not sure what is happening. I checked logs too. I am using Amazon SES SMTP credentials for the same.

Comment: @Anshita add a new column in your table for ex. `in_queue` default 0 and in the cron add a logic to fetch only those emails whose `in_queue` value is `0`. Also add a logic to update `in_queue` flag to 1 for all the emails which cron has fetched from the DB. Using this method, no email will be processed again by the cron whether the email sent / in progress.

Comment: @VidhyutPandya I already have coded my controller that way. All the emails will be processed only if they both flags i.e "Processed" & "Email Sent" to 0, but still, I faced the issue with Cron. I am not sure if two server PIDs might have been clashing that has duplicate email logs to process.